# Converting Inline query to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I have a vb.net code with inline query as below. I need to convert the inline query to a stored procedure.

In that case the stored procedure will be executed for each row which will result in performance issue.

Please suggest me some solutions to avoid multiple call to stored procedure.

```
 If Not chkShowAll.Checked Then
    For Each _row As DataGridViewRow In dgInvestor.Rows
       If ValidateDate(_row.Cells(2).Value.ToString, _Date) Then
          sSQL = "INSERT INTO INVESTOR_ACCOUNT VALUES('" & _row.Cells(0).Value & "'," & _row.Cells(1).Value & "," & _Date & ")"
         _Dta.RunQuery(cn, sSQL)
       End If
    Next
 End IF
```

Comment: You can use BulkInsert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 and above, you can use table-valued parameter to pass all rows into SP at a time. see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22392/SQL-Server-Table-Valued-Parameters) article Or you can pass xml to SP as parameter and parse that xml into table for SQL Server 2005 [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters)

Comment: In case of Table-valued parameter.. I have multiple tables on which insert queries needs to be executed. So do i need to create seperate User Defined Type for each Table?

Comment: that depends, you can have as many columns as you want in a table valued parameter. But if you tell me your requirement, I can help you better.